# PHP: Generate dynamic sized image based on string

Tags: php, string, image, png

I'm trying to make a "button generator" that outputs a PNG image with specified text on it. The only thing I need to do now is to figure out how to make the button resize dynamically compared to the text's length. Specifically, I need it to:

1. Output the left half of the button (so that the button would be rounded).
2. Check how many pixels the string takes up and output a 1 pixel wide image that many times.
3. Output the right half of the button (which may be the left one flipped, doesn't really matter).
4. Output the string in the exact middle.

If anyone could give me an example on how to accomplish this I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resizing depending on text you can use [imagettfbbox(float $size , float $angle , string $fontfile , string $text ) function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) For tile image from step 2 you can use [imagesettile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesettile.php) function.
Your steps could be something like this:

1. calculate string width (and height) using imagettfbbox
2. add left and right sides widths with spacing and create image with this
   size
3. draw left and right "halves" of button and "middle" using
   imagesettile & imagefilledrectangle
4. output string in "left
   half"+"spacing" position using imagettftext function.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can execute "convert" (from the Image Magick package) to manipulate images to your hearts content on the server, during a post-back. You didn't specify the server platform, so I'll just leave this here for you:

https://www.php.net/function.exec

And:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention it. I'm using Windows at the moment (as my testing server) and am going to use Debian 6 for my live site, but I need this to work on both.

Comment: You should install on your windows machine a VM with Debian 6 as close to the server environment as possible or you might find platform incompatibilities later on. Consider AT LEAST [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for Linux.